Is there anything wrong with my proxy-implemetation contracts
I just used openzeppelin TransparentUpgradeableProxy, the contractas are like below, is there anything wrong?
//storage contract
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";

contract XStorage is Ownable {
    //state variables...
    
    //contractor
    constructor() Ownable(msg.sender) {}
}

//proxy contract
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/proxy/transparent/TransparentUpgradeableProxy.sol";

contract XProxy is XStorage, TransparentUpgradeableProxy {
    constructor(address _imp) TransparentUpgradeableProxy(_imp, msg.sender, bytes('')) {}
    receive() external payable { }
}

//Implementation v1
contract XImple is XStorage {
    //some implementation functions, no state variable
    function abc() external {
    }
}

the basic idea is that imp&proxy share the storage structure, openzeppelin: TransparentUpgradeableProxy provide ability to do upgrade, is there anything wrong with my contracts?
I ask because someone told me that my implementation is not 'upgradeable', but I test with  hardhat and it seems ok?

I think your code is ok, but it's better for the proxy contract not to inherit any implementation contract.
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity 0.8.20;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/proxy/transparent/TransparentUpgradeableProxy.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts-upgradeable/access/OwnableUpgradeable.sol";

contract XStorage is OwnableUpgradeable {
    function initialize(address owner) external initializer {
        __Ownable_init(owner);
    }
}

contract XProxy is TransparentUpgradeableProxy {
    constructor(address _imp, bytes memory _data)
        TransparentUpgradeableProxy(_imp, msg.sender, _data)
    {}
}

in TransparentUpgradeableProxy.sol
contract TransparentUpgradeableProxy {
    constructor(address _logic, address initialOwner, bytes memory _data) payable ERC1967Proxy(_logic, _data) {
        _admin = address(new ProxyAdmin(initialOwner));
        // Set the storage value and emit an event for ERC-1967 compatibility
        ERC1967Utils.changeAdmin(_proxyAdmin());
    }
}

Note: In the latest oppenzeppelin, TransparentUpgradeableProxy will deploy the ProxyAdmin contract. If you want to upgrade, you must call ProxyAdmin with initialOwner.

thanks for reply, your solution move all storage layout to imp. Since the admin in TransparentUpgradeableProxy is immutable, and implementation address use  a hardcoded   bytes32 internal constant IMPLEMENTATION_SLOT so the Proxy contract has no assumption about storage.
only implementation contract inherit XStorage, the owner setup code moved to IMP.
so the deplolyment should be deploy IMP first, then deploy proxy with  (IMP, calldata of initialize(msg.sender))  to link proxy to IMP and call IMP's initialize(msg.sender), right?

@Jerrylk yes, first deploy IMP,and second deploy proxy with (_imp, calldata).
